# How to enlarge root (/) partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have installed 14.04 LTS on a 512GB disk. I am cloning it to a 1TB disk and would like to extend the root (/) partition. Currently the /dev/sda5 partition has both the root (/) and the swap mount points (this is how the install CD configured the disk).

```
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0   477G  0 disk
├─sda1                           8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                           8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                           8:5    0 476.7G  0 part
  ├─datanode--vg-root (dm-0)   252:0    0 220.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─datanode--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) 252:1    0   241G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

I am able to use Gparted to extend the /dev/sda5 partition to use the whole disk but because both the root and swap are mounted to the same partition I have not been able to extend the root (/).

I am new to Linux and am in need of some help.

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand an encrypted ubuntu partition with LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747073/how-to-expand-an-encrypted-ubuntu-partition-with-lvm)

Answer (score 1):

gparted may not allow you to resize the `mounted` & `active` root `/` partition when you are logged into Ubuntu (i.e. mounted `/`). There are many solutions to resize the root partition depending on your knowledge and experience. However, I would suggest using the `gparted live CD`. Burn the `iso` to **USB** or **CD** and boot your system from it. Once booted, you can make changes to the `root partition` and the `root filesystem`. Bonus for using `gparted` is that it gives you `GUI`.

[gparted Live CD](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)

Comment: I did use the Gparted live CD but there is still the problem of both the root and swap mount points on the same partition.

Comment: strange. how about if you use the `fdisk` i.e. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-resize-ext4-root-partition-live-without-umount

Answer (score 1):

I see that your SWAP is 241GB - you have to reduce the size. It is huge size for SWAP.
What I recommend it is to delete the swap partition (datanode--vg-swap_1), extend the root / partition (leave free space for the SWAP partition) and create new SWAP partition with the left free space. This is for your case.
The other option is to reduce the SWAP space and extend the root LVM partition.

Comment: The swap mount is not a partition, it is a mount on a LVM partition. I am not sure how I would delete the swap in this configuration.

Comment: You can see in this article https://askubuntu.com/questions/532121/problem-removing-swap-partition
Sorry for the link but I am trying to be shorter and we can escape from duplications.